# How to multiply a single row with a number from column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case there are orders and order positions. Each order position has a quantity. For example:

[image]

But now I need a single row for each "position element". This is the output I want:

[image]

My idea is to use `rank()` / `over()` to get the incremental number, but I don't know how to use the quantity as multiplicator.

Is there a smart solution to use a single colum as "row multiplicator"? A sql function or a loop is not possible in my case, just plain sql :)

Thank you! :)

---

With the query from `gvee` I was able to create a solution for my problem:

```
Select 
BelPosId as OrderPositionId, 
Artikelnummer as ProductId,  
Bezeichnung1 as ProductName,
Menge as Quantity,
NumberTable.number+1 as ElementId
FROM KHKVKBelegePositionen 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT (a.number * 256) + b.number As number
FROM     (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As a
 CROSS
  JOIN (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As b) NumberTable

ON

NumberTable.number < Menge
```

The trick was to `inner join` the column "quantity" to the "number" column from the numbers table with the `less than` operator to simulate a "multiplicator":

[image]

Comment: What is the output you want? You want to multiply what by quantity?

Comment: The first screenshot is the current sql statement. The second one is the result how it should be :) [I used union to force the view und set the ID manually.]

Comment: @StefanBrendle Provide your query with `Union` clause .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join to a numbers table!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.numbers (
   number int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.numbers
ADD
   CONSTRAINT pk_numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (number)
     WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.numbers (number)
SELECT (a.number * 256) + b.number As number
FROM     (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As a
 CROSS
  JOIN (
        SELECT number
        FROM   master..spt_values
        WHERE  type = 'P'
        AND    number <= 255
       ) As b
```

Here's where I keep my latest script: http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql

Once you have this in place you perform a simple join:

```
SELECT KHKVKBelegePositionen.BelPosId As OrderPositionId
     , KHKVKBelegePositionen.Artikelnummer As ProductId
     , KHKVKBelegePositionen.Bezeichung1 As ProductName
     , KHKVKBelegePositionen.Menge As Quantity
     , numbers.number As ElemendId
FROM   KHKVKBelegePositionen
 INNER
  JOIN dbo.numbers
    ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND KHKVKBelegePositionen.Menge
```

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of smart querys in your link! Thank you! :)

Comment: I created a solution with the query in your link, I've updated the post above, it works perfect :)

Comment: @StefanBrendle I highly recommend that you create a physical numbers table. They come in very handy! Also this will give you the added benefit of index usage.

Comment: @gvee +1 for a good solution but can you put the script for the numbers table into this answer to make it even better and useful for others.

Comment: @Szymon good point. Answer updated to include numbers table script/

Answer (score 7):

You can use that script which doesn't require any external tables:

```
SELECT t.quantity, 
       n.num 
FROM   table10 t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_number() 
                            OVER( 
                              ORDER BY object_id) num 
                   FROM   sys.all_objects) n 
               ON t.quantity >= n.num
```

I didn't include other columns but you can just add them to the `select` list

Comment: And you'll need to give SELECT permission on sys.all_objects to users. Although, it can be used for ad-hoc queries.

Comment: @Igor Not really. Citing MSDN: The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission.

Comment: @Szymon so if a user only has access to 5 items then the maximum quantity they can query for is 5 ;)

Comment: @gvee Well, it could be limited but not to such a low number usually. Physical table that you used is better provided that you can create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it creating table with numbers:

```
/* table variable is used just for example. 
   It's better to create table and fill it with numbers once*/   

declare @numbers table(i int)

declare @i int=1

while @i<100
begin
    insert into @numbers values (@i)

    set @i=@i+1
end

declare @your_table table (N int)

insert into @your_table values (10),(1),(5)


select yt.N, n.i
from @your_table yt
     join @numbers n ON n.i<=yt.N
order by yt.N, n.i
```