# Select statement that duplicates rows based on N value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a Power table that stores building circuit details. A circuit can be 1 phase or 3 phase but is always represented as 1 row in the circuit table.

I want to insert the details of the circuits into a join table which joins panels to circuits
My current circuit table has the following details

```
CircuitID | Voltage | Phase | PanelID | Cct | 
    1     |   120   |   1   |    1    |   1 |
    2     |   208   |   3   |    1    |   3 |
    3     |   208   |   2   |    1    |   8 |
```

Is it possible to create a select where by when it sees a 3 phase row it selects 3 rows (or 2 select 2 rows) and increments the Cct column by 1 each time or do I have to create a loop?

```
CircuitID | PanelID | Cct | 
    1     |    1    |   1 |
    2     |    1    |   3 |
    2     |    1    |   4 |
    2     |    1    |   5 |
    3     |    1    |   8 |
    3     |    1    |   9 |
```

Comment: Is that expected result really what you expect? 2 3 times, and 3 2 times...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540211/how-to-multiply-a-single-row-with-a-number-from-column-in-sql

Comment: Yes, 2 and 3 are the Circuit numbers. It's the phase that increments. Didn't mean to be confusing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a one recursive cte.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [CircuitID], [Voltage], [Phase], [PanelID], [Cct], [Cct] AS [Ref]  
    FROM [Power]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [CircuitID], [Voltage], [Phase], [PanelID], [Cct] + 1, [Ref]  
    FROM cte 
    WHERE [Cct] + 1 < [Phase]  + [Ref] 
)
SELECT [CircuitID], [PanelID], [Cct] 
FROM cte
ORDER BY [CircuitID]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that recursive CTE is equivalent to loop

Comment: @MotoGP  i dont see a huge downfall to that in this case.. maybe on a really large scale.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LOdbZ.png

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it

First generate numbers using tally table(best possible way). Here is one excellent article about generating number without loops. [Generate a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Then join the numbers table with yourtable where `phase` value of each record should be greater than sequence number in number's table

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
numbers as ( SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3 )
SELECT CircuitID,
        PanelID,
        Cct = Cct + ( n - 1 )
FROM   Yourtable a
        JOIN numbers b
            ON a.Phase >= b.n
```

Comment: This doesn't increment the `Cct`

Comment: @JamieD77 - Updated check now

Comment: @MotoGP he is not the OP.. I don't understand how your answer got upvote and mine didn't :S its as simple as hell

Comment: @sagi - Simple. Mine will fetch the expected result and your's wont. Your result won't even have similar number of records in result

Comment: :S forgot the IN() , it does now .. I'm tired.

Comment: @sagi - I think you should get some sleep ;) Still it will not produce expected result

Comment: Yes it will ... Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way,

```
Select y.* from (
Select 1 CircuitID,120 Voltage,1 Phase,1 PanelID, 1 Cct
union
Select 2,208,3,1,3
union
Select 3,208,2,1,8)y, 
(Select 1 x
union 
Select 2 x
union 
Select 3 x)x
Where x.x <= y.Phase
```

Directly copy paste this and try, it will run 100%. After that, just replace my 'y' table with your real table.