# Multiply rows by difference of numbers in columns, with sequence list

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a table using postgres that multiplies a row by the difference of the numbers in 2 columns, and provides the corresponding sequence. It's hard to explain, I'll leave a picture to save us a thousand words:

[image]

I have found a partial answer to this question in SQL, but it only multiplies by one column, and I'm having trouble with using it in Posgresql:
[How to multiply a single row with a number from column in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540211/how-to-multiply-a-single-row-with-a-number-from-column-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generate_series` function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

```
create table table_a(
  a       integer primary key,
  start_a integer,
  end_a   integer
);

insert into table_a values
  (1, 1, 3), 
  (2, 2, 5);

create table table_b as 
  select a, start_a, end_a, g as start_b, g+1 as end_b
    from table_a, lateral generate_series(start_a, end_a-1) g;

select * from table_b;
```

You can try it here: http://rextester.com/RTZWK4070

Comment: So, it turns out that I needed to do things a little differently. I'd love to verify your results, but this is actually the problem I'm facing, if you can help me:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288124/join-2-tables-where-two-sets-of-numbers-overlap-within-the-joining-columns

Thanks a ton for your help either way :)