# Join 2 tables where two sets of numbers overlap within the joining columns

Tags: postgresql

**I need to join 2 tables with postgresql where two sets of numbers overlap within the joining columns.**

---

The image below explains it - I am needing to take a table of congresspeople and their party affiliation and join it with a table of districts (based on when the districts were drawn or redrawn). The result will be the rows that show the dates that the district, state and congressperson were the same. Wherever there are dates of a district that are known and the congressperson dates are unknown, the dates that are known for the district are filled for that portion, and the dates for the congressperson are left blank - and vice versa.

[image]

---

For example, for the first rows in the tables:

---

Congressperson Table:

```
Arkansas, District 5, Republican: 1940-1945
```

District Table:

```
Arkansas, District 5: 1942-1963
```

Results in the following combinations (Start_Comb and End_Comb):

```
1940-1942
1942-1945
```

And for the combination where the district is unknown (1940-1942), the district dates are left blank.

The final set of date columns (gray) is simply the combinations that are only for the district (this is super easy).

---

In case you're wondering what this is for, I am creating an animated map, kind of like this, but for congressional districts over time:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQDyn04vtf8

I'll end up with something where there is a map where for every known district, there is a known or unknown party.

---

Haven't got very far, this is what I did:

```
SELECT *
FROM congressperson
JOIN districts
ON Start_Dist BETWEEN Start_Cong AND End_Cong
WHERE district.A = district.B
OR End_Dist BETWEEN Start_Cong AND Start_Dist
OR Start_Cong = Start_Dist OR End_Cong= End_Dist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to make list of unique dates from both tables first. Then for each such date find next date (in this particular case dates are grouped by state, district, and next date is looked for particular state, district).
 
So now we have list of ranges we are looking for. Now we can join (for this paticular task left join) other tables by required conditions:

```
select
    r.state,
    c.start_cong,
    c.end_cong,
    c.party,
    coalesce(c.district, d.district) district,
    d.start_dist,
    d.end_dist,
    start_comb,
    end_comb,
    case when d.district is not null then start_comb end final_start,
    case when d.district is not null then end_comb end final_end
from (
    with dates as (
        select
            *
        from (
            SELECT 
                c.state,
                c.district,
                start_cong date
            FROM congressperson c
            union 
            SELECT
                c.state,
                c.district, 
                end_cong
            FROM congressperson c
            union 
            SELECT 
                d.state,
                d.district,
                start_dist
            FROM district d 
            union 
            SELECT
                d.state,
                d.district, 
                end_dist
            FROM district d 
        ) DATES
        group by 
            state,
            district,
            date
        order by 
            state,
            district,    
            date
    ) 
    select
        dates.state,
        dates.district,
        dates.date start_comb,
    (select 
        d.date 
    from 
        dates d
    where
        d.state = dates.state and
        d.district = dates.district and
        d.date > dates.date
    order by 
        d.date
    limit 1
    ) end_comb
    from 
        dates) r
left join congressperson c on 
                            c.state = r.state and
                            c.district = r.district and
                            start_comb between c.start_cong and c.end_cong and 
                            end_comb between c.start_cong and c.end_cong
left join district d on 
                        d.state = r.state and
                        d.district = r.district and
                        start_comb between d.start_dist and d.end_dist and 
                        end_comb between d.start_dist and d.end_dist
where
    end_comb is not null 
order by 
    r.state, coalesce(c.district, d.district), start_comb, end_comb, start_cong, end_cong
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Your answer would be greatly improved if you added a couple sentences about how your query solves the problem.